# ASP.NET MVC Routing Assistance

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have an ASP.NET MVC 2 web application which is supposed to receive a request from a rather stupid system. The system in question expects it to be a PHP site. It's not. The request I get is of the form:

```
http://myIP/index.php?oa=val1&da=val1&ud=val1
```

I have a controller with a method

```
Index(string oa, string da, string ud)
```

But I don't know how to get this request routed to this controller. I have tried

```
routes.MapRoute(  
  "R",  
  "index.php/{oa}/{da}/{ud}",  
  new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }  
);
```

But to no avail. It works if the request comes in the format Index.php/val1/val2/val3, but when the request comes as shown above, it generates a 404.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply map the route to the "php" page. The query string parameters will not transpose into the route data.

```
routes.MapRoute("R","index.php", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
```

and then for your action on the controller

```
public ActionResult Index() {
    string oa = Request.QueryString["oa"];
    string da = Request.QueryString["da"];
    string ud = Request.QueryString["ud"];

    //do the rest of your logic here (obviously)

    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The route doesn't work because the QueryString is not part of the RouteData. It's best to keep route values separate to query params.

I would simply map index.php and then access the query string in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the this routing:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "php", 
            "index.php", 
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", 
                  id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

and use this method:

```
public ActionResult Index(string oa, string da, string ud){
   ....
}
```